# Can i configure a Facebook app with multiple domains?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I've seen this question earlier on your website, but it didn't quite help me out yet...

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a Content Management System (PHP) that is installed on the server of the various websites of my customers. Whenever a user posts a new message on his website, a shorter version of this message is sent to social media sites. Right now, this is possible with twitter (using the OAuth library). But I would want it to work with facebook too....

When I create an app in Facebook i HAVE to assign ONE return URL. But because the to-be-used CMS system can be anywhere, it's quite useless to me?

Or is there a way to make this work?

Best regars, Robert

Comment: I am afraid that you will need to get an api-key for each domain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your exact need for the return URL here. However, having the CMS communicate with Facebook from the server side would be performed with the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) with the OpenGraph protocol.  This sounds like what you are doing with Twitter's OAuth.

You can then code your CMS to use your API credentials and never leave the CMS server. There is even a [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) available for Facebook which sounds like it would integrate well for you.

If the CMS is at a different URL for each individual, then they each need to create an app on their Facebook profile to add the communication in this method.  Because Facebook requires the basename of the URL to be the same by design, for security.  This is typically performed by enabling the end-user to configure their own "app" in their profile for communication and is very commonly done with Wordpress applications for the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm still left with the same question. I use the PHP SDK to connect to facebook, but I get an error when I'm trying to connect.

The tutorial on the facebook developers page tells me I have to set a return url (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) But I want it to be on different domains (e.g. example.com and anotherexample.com).

Comment: Sorry that didn't answer, I misread the CMS location. I've edited appropriately.  Hope it helps more now.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It's really a shame. I don't want my customers to go through so much "trouble" for a function as simple as that. Guess i'll try to fix it differently. Thanks again!